# Laravel rout not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
     return 'foo';
    //return View::make('hello');
    //return View::make('world');
});
```

When I type `http://localhost/laravel/`, It displays `foo`.

BUT

With this rout

```
 Route::get('about', function()
    {
         return 'foo';
        //return View::make('hello');
        //return View::make('world');
    });
```

AND `http://localhost/laravel/about`, I get
 `The requested URL /laravel/about was not found on this server`.

Please explain me what is going on here.

Comment: What kind of server do you use? If this is some other then Apache you need to redirect requests to index.php; like they did in the [.htaccess for apache](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)

Comment: Its Apache, i am using Wamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using link: `localhost/laravel/index.php/about` route works. It means you are defining them correctly. The problem is on server side. Make sure your `mod_rewrite` module is enabled.

You are using Wamp. Try to follow this instructions:
http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/enable-apache-rewrite-module.html

Comment: No it dosen't work. The route would work even if i do this `Route::get('', function()` insted of `Route::get('/', function()`

Comment: Wow that works actually..but how please can you explain.

Comment: The answer here explains it. You do not have mod_rewrite enabled